# Strengthening Wi-Fi signal

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, layer1

The company has a Wi-Fi network, and the company area is quite large. There is a dead zone in which the Internet is not available by client devices (about 30% of the total area). There were attempts to use the router as a repeater, but they were not crowned with success, as it was impossible to trace the users connected to the repeater (all users show up as a repeater). As far as I know, the repeater also does not nave a very good effect on network bandwidth.

Are there any ways to enhance the Wi-Fi signal without using repeaters? Using a cable is not considered as an option. It is also necessary that the network need to has *seamless roaming*.

Comment: at the very best you could increase the power on the APs, also what vendor solution are you using?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to add an additional AP with a directional antenna to improve reception in the dead zone.  As @RonMaupin says, you will need a site survey to determine if this is possible. Repeaters are usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Wi-Fi wasn't set up properly in the first place.

You probably want to do it correctly, or you will continually run into problems. This involves performing a wireless site survey to identify proper WAP placement. After you get the survey, you need to install the WAPs, probably with a wireless controller to get seamless roaming. This will involve cabling for the WAPs (wireless is *not* completely wireless). After implementation, you should perform another wireless site survey in order to be able to tweak the WAP placements and radio strengths.

This is how companies do successful Wi-Fi design and implementation. Also, you don't own the airwaves and cannot control other wireless implementations which may happen close by and cause interference. The use of monitoring WAPs can help identify sources of interference which didn't exist before, and you may need to modify the AP placements and radio power over time to adjust for changing wireless conditions.